# Problem dealing with two correlated Random Variables

Tags: probability, statistics

Here is a problem and my solution to it. I ran some simulations in R, and I
concluded that I am wrong. I am hoping that somebody can tell me where I
went wrong.

Thanks, Bob

Problem:

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two independent normally distributed random variables
with $u = 0$ and $\sigma = 1$. Let $Z = \frac{1}{2}X + \frac{1}{2}Y$. What is
the correlation between $X$ and $Z$?

Answer:

\begin{eqnarray*}
\rho_{xz} &=& \frac{cov(X,Z)}{var(X) var(Z)}\\
cov(X,Z) &=& \frac{1}{2}cov(X,X) + \frac{1}{2}cov(X,Y) \\
cov(X,X) &=& 1 \\
cov(X,Y) &=& 0 \\
cov(X,Z) &=& \frac{1}{2}(1) + \frac{1}{2}(0) = \frac{1}{2} \\
\rho_{xz} &=& \frac{\frac{1}{2}}{1(1)}\\
\rho_{xz} &=& \frac{1}{2} \\
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is that the variance of $Z$ is not $1$.  This is because if $Z = (X+Y)/2$, the variance of $Z$ is a quarter of the sum of the variances of $X$ and $Y$; i.e., $\operatorname{Var}[Z] = 2/4 = 1/2$.  Now, the other problem is that the correlation is not defined as you have it:  it is $$\rho_{XZ} = \frac{\operatorname{Cov}[X,Z]}{\sqrt{\operatorname{Var}[X]}\sqrt{\operatorname{Var}[Z]}}.$$  Intuitively, you should know that the variance of a sample mean of IID variables will be less than the variance of any individual observation.